# Error running a executable file in Mac Catalina

Tags: macos, unix, macos-catalina

[image: It's not telling me anything else, so I don't know why it not working.]

I am trying to run this exec file on my mac. I am not sure what the reason is for this error. I am trying to execute a binary file for a c program. The output should just be strings and the input is the trace.config and trace.dat files.

Comment: What is the output of `file memhier_ref` ?

Comment: The output should just be strings and the input is the trace.config and trace.dat files.

Comment: Can you type the command `file memhier_ref` and tell us what its output is? It's possible that `memhier_ref` is meant to run either on a different version of MacOS or for a different system altogether, such as Linux.

Comment: File memier_ref gives me " ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=11e05b7bd71237a761192c9b8d2a16898f60a60d, not stripped". does that mean I need to run in on LINUX.

Comment: That's a linux executable, not a Mac OS one... naturally it's not going to run.

Comment: If you have the source, you can try compiling the proper version. Otherwise, yeah, run it on a linux VM or computer.

Comment: Thank you guys, I appreciate it.